# $\ln x \leq x-1$ for all $x\ge 1$

Tags: calculus

> Let $x \geq 1$. Show that $\ln x \leq x-1$.

I used the mean value theorem to show that $\ln x \leq x-1$.
But then they ask us to deduce that $e^t \geq x+1$. I know that $\ln x$ and $e^x$ are inverse but I am not able to solve it.

Comment: "> or equal" is $\ge$ `$\ge$`

Comment: At least the case $x=1$ is done by you. So we can delete the "or equal" several times.

Comment: And $<$ or equal is $\le$ ``$\le$``

Comment: No need for "or equal" anymore ... so $x>1$ is OK.

Comment: Or if you like, `$\geqslant$` and `$\leqslant$` to give the $\geqslant$ and $\leqslant$ variant for no benefit except eye-candy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that $\log x \le x-1$ for all $x \ge1$ then

$$e^{\log(x)} \le e^{x-1}  \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad e^x\ge ex \ge x+1$$

Answer (score 5):

Let $y\geq 0$. Then $e^y\geq 1$, and from what you already proved,  it follows
$$y= \ln (e^y)\leq e^y-1 \quad \Longrightarrow y+1 \leq e^y\,.$$